# Is it valid for Chrome to include TABLE inside P?

Tags: html

The following code:

```
<p>Some words

<table>
...
</table>
```

results under Google Chrome in the nesting `html > body > p > table`. I realize there is a "missing" `</p>`, but on the other hand at least in HTML4 [P cannot contain block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P). Why does Chrome then allow TABLE to live inside P?

Thanks.

Comment: the browser can allow many things. just try not to put it there

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Version 23.0.1271.64 m http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/D3gBc/

Comment: Use a doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html>` and it won't happen.

Comment: Musa, try not using a doctype... I thought that was OK in 2012!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome does not allow that.
If you try it, Chrome's parser will implicitly close the `<p>` tag before the `<table>`.

This behavior is required by the spec and is tested for by the Acid2 test.

Comment: Note that in quirks mode, the parser works differently, and in that case the `table` element does get placed inside the `p` element.

Comment: OK, sorry: I thought it was OK in HTML5 not to include even the doctype. (Thanks Alohci.) Thanks to all for the prompt feedback.